# An asymptotic series for the digamma function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

As we know, there is an asymptotic series for the digamma function when $z>0$ is a real number.
$$
\psi(z)=\ln z+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{B_n}{nz^n}}
$$
$B_n$ is the first Bernoulli numbers.

How to make a proof?

Comment: Do you know that other famous asymptotic series, by Stirling? Might there be a connection to this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove this, using Euler-Maclaurin Formula.
Here is a introduction from Wikipedia.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

This is a quite easy problem.
To Admin,
You may be able to consider deleting this question, thanks. ^_^